# Windows using full internet bandwidth continuously

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, bandwidth

I am using windows 10 pro for couple of months. I had no problem like this in past. My internet speed is 1.5 mbps. A windows built in program called `svchost.exe (netsvcs)` is taking all of my bandwidth and I can't even visit any website.
Here are some screen shots:[image: image 1]

[image]

**Disclaimer:** I am 100% sure this not happening for windows update and my system is up to date. I dont use any antivirus like avast or avg .I use windows defender and it is also up to date.

What can I do to prevent this?

**Edit:**

No one couldn't give me any correct method(answer). I think I have to uninstall windows and install linux or buy a mac. It's a super buggy os and the start menu crashes 100 times a day! I have to lose my favourite programs which is not available in mac or linux! Some one marked this question as duplicate. This is a different question.

Comment: `svchosts` is a service host process, so it isn't actually a thing, but many things run within it. see more here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/what-is-svchostexe-and-why-is-it-running/ In order to see what services are running inside that process, note the PID (1012 in the image you posted), and  in an elevated command prompt, run `tasklist /svc`. in the output, look for the process PID, and you should see a list of the services running. you can control these services in the services.msc control panel application.

Comment: What about drive activity? Is there anything being written to disk? Note that 21,000 B/s = .17Mbps, so that screenshot isn't painting a full picture of bandwidth

Comment: As your question is written, people are interpreting it to be the same as the other question (or to at least be answered by answers there).  So it will attract the same answers, which would be wasted duplication of effort.  Just saying it isn't a duplicate won't change how people respond to it.  To reopen your question, people need to understand how it's different and how the answers there don't help.  Can you clearly differentiate your question so that it attracts different answers?

Answer (score 0):

Netsvcs is associated with BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service). Quick fix is to disable it from the Services MMC, but it will hinder you from receiving updates. Instead, look at your Windows Update settings. Make sure that your machine is not set to host updates for other machines and that you aren't downloading updates from multiple sources. Details on Windows Update settings in Windows 10 are documented here:

[Windows Update and Security Settings in Windows 10](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-update-security-settings-windows-10)

Comment: I tried this and nothing happend. When I restart it goes back to active.

Answer (score 0):

You will find that `svchost.exe` has been known to be a resource hog.  Typically, we can utilize tools like the built-in Windows `Task Manager` and [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to help determine the root cause of the problem.  Here is a good tutorial that describes the process in-depth:

[What Is svchost.exe and Why Is It Running?](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/what-is-svchostexe-and-why-is-it-running/)